# How to directly send colors to the OpenGL shader

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have started OpenGL game development about 5 months ago. When i first started game development i wached a tutorial about a game engine. But now a fiew months later i would like to edit one of the openGL parts on that game engine but i have no idea how.

I would not like to use texture coords and a corresponding image but just use RGB collors that i parse to the OpenGL shader.

The code i use to render entities:

```
public void render(Map<TexturedModel, List<Entity>> entities){
    for(TexturedModel model:entities.keySet()){
        prepareTexturedModel(model);
        List<Entity> batch = entities.get(model);
        for(Entity entity:batch){
            prepareInstance(entity);
            GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, model.getRawModel().getVertexCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        }
        unbindTexturedModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which game engine are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have direct access to the shader object (which should be a primitive integer) you can do this:

in the *fragment* shader, which will probably end in .frag or .fsh:

```
uniform vec3 myColor;
out vec4 fragColor;
void main(){
    fragColor=vec4(myColor,1.0);
}
```

In the Java code, per-frame AFTER you have called `glUseProgram(shaderID)`, you need to call `glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderID,"myColor"),red,green,blue);` where `red`, `green` and `blue` are floats in the range `[0,1]`.  If you don't have access to the integer shader id, then it really depends on which game engine you are using.